# SQL Turkish Language displaying issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am displaying data with Turkish characters from SQL database of Godaddy but I have issue that it displays `Kadıkoy` word to `Kad?koy`. I have set the type to text and collation to utf-8_turkish_ci but it didn't work. Even I have tried ucs2_turkish_ci and latin5_turkish_ci but didn't work.

So please where could be my problem?

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Comment: try `set names 'utf8'` at the begin of the batch

Comment: please check [Solution 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517189/turkish-characters-are-not-displayed-correctly) and [Solution 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207043/mysql-encoding-issue-with-turkish-characters)

Comment: @eggyal I have tried that too nothing change.

Comment: @user2511414 I have tried that too nothing change.

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan I have this already in my code 

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"; Do I need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the file is actually saved in UTF-8 format.
Then check that you have 
meta tag `Content-Type` in your html content is `"text/html;charset=UTF-8"`

In your HTML header:

You can also try calling `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the beginning of your `PHP` script or adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to your `.htaccess` file.